# Deserialize header in jaxws handler

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, cxf

I am using a jax-ws Handler to intercept a SOAP message so that I can grab certain elements from the Header.  Is there a way to deserialize a Header and parse it into either wsdl2java or xmlbeans generated object?  I am currently migrating from AXIS to CXF.  Under AXIS, I could get the Header xml and parse it using a Factory class.  I have not found a good way to do this with the objects generated from CXF wsdl2java.  I realize that I can use the getElementsByTagName to retrieve each Node, but it is just easier to work with the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SAAJ API to manipulate the SOAP message directly. Extend `AbstractSoapInterceptor` by implementing the `handleMessage()` method and add it to the chain of InInterceptors.

```
public class MyCustomInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) throws Fault {
    try {
        SOAPMessage message = soapMessage.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);
        SOAPPart sp = message.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope se = sp.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody sb = se.getBody();
        SOAPHeader sh = se.getHeader();

    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.error(e);
        throw new Fault(e);
    }

    }


}
```

**NOTE**: You will also need to attach `SAAJInInterceptor` to the chain of interceptors or else `soapMessage.getContent(SOAPMessage.class)` will return `null`

Comment: But I would like to work with the java2wsdl generated classes and not the CXF SOAPMessage, SOAPBody, etc. Is there a way to parse/cast the SOAPMessage to the generated classes?